# SQL: How to create a query to order database by order ID and products inside of it

Tags: sql

I am currently in a situation where I cannot think of a way out. To explain my problem I will first post a very simplified version of the database I am using:

```
  ID:   Place:   Product:
111111    1     Product A   
222222    1     Product A   
222222    2     Product B   
333333    1     Product A   
444444    1     Product A   
444444    2     Product B   
444444    3     Product C   
555555    1     Product A
```

Above 3 columns are mentioned. The first column "ID:" represents the unique ID each order has. The second "Place:" represents the position of a certain item in an order. If the order is made up of only 1 product, there will be only one row corresponding to it in the database:

```
111111    1     Product A
```

If the order has two or more products in it, there will be two or more rows in the database with the same value in the "ID:" column and the "Place:" column will represent the position of the item in the order.

```
222222    1     Product A   
222222    2     Product B
-------------------------
444444    1     Product A   
444444    2     Product B   
444444    3     Product C
```

The third column "Product:" is pretty much obvious- it represents the name of the product.

My question is the following:

Is it possible to make a query which would find the different types of orders and count them? For example, if the order is made up of only "Product A" this should be a unique type of order. If the order consists of "Product A" in place 1 and "Product B" in place 2 (or vice versa) then that would be a unique order as well. It should look like this:

```
    Type:       Count()
  Product A       3
 Product A,B      1
Product A,B,C     1
```

I tried numerous queries but the results that I get are far from what I am looking for. Any hints would be very appreciated!

I apologize if the answer is easy or obvious. I am not very experienced with SQL yet.

Thank you in advance, Petar

Comment: Which [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: Is `Product a,b` considered different than `Product b,a`?

Comment: Mureinik, it s Postresql database and I am using Metabase to view it.

Comment: Zohar, the ideal case would be that Product a,b and Product b,a should be considered the same. However, the other option wont be perfect but would help me a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using mysql, you can use the [group_concat](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function, and run a query like this:

```
select type, count(1) from 
(
SELECT group_concat(PRODUCT ORDER BY PRODUCT) type 
FROM products
GROUP BY ID
) a
group by type;
```

but I must warn you, this query will be executed using temporary and filesort

Comment: This was what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

(select count(Product) as cnt1,ID from test1
GROUP BY ID)

Kindly share what exactly output you want in display.May be this will help you.